# import/export issue of angularjs constants

Tags: angularjs, commonjs

I am using common js module system in my angularjs 1.x application and struggling with importing/exporting constants. This is what I have.

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
var angular = require('angular');    
module.exports = angular.module('constants', [])
    .constant('constant1', require('./constant1'))
     .constant('constant2', require('./constant2'))
    .constant('constant3', require('./constant3'))
```

**constant1.js**

```
'use strict';
 var SAMPLE1 =  { 'TEST1' : 100 , 'Test2': 200 }
 var SAMPLE2 =  300;
module.exports = SAMPLE1 ;
module.exports = SAMPLE2 ;
```

**constant2.js**

```
 'use strict';
      var SAMPLE3 =  { 'TEST3' : 400 , 'Test4': 500 }
      var SAMPLE4 =  600;
module.exports = SAMPLE3 ;
module.exports = SAMPLE4 ;
```

**constant3.js**

```
 'use strict';
      var SAMPLE5 =  { 'TEST5' : 700 , 'Test6': 800 }
      var SAMPLE6 =  900;
module.exports = SAMPLE5 ;
module.exports = SAMPLE6 ;
```

**app.module.js**

```
'use strict';
var angular = require('angular');
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    require('./common/services').name,
    require('./components/constants').name
]);
```

**I am getting this error while running the application**

Error: $injector:unpr

Unknown provider: KEYProvider <- SAMPLE1 <- MyService

Comment: @GProst- That worked!!: :) Thank you! If you can post this as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says you have an error in declaration of injections of your service `MyService`. If you want to export multiple variables you have to write `module.exports.var1 = var1; module.exports.var2 = var2` (or `exports.var1 = var1; exports.var2 = var2`) and not just `module.exports = var1; module.exports = var2,` because the second assignment simply overrides the first one. Later you use `var1 = require('./file').var1` to import var1 and `var2 = require('./file').var2` to import var2